# Get a Chrome URL

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to get a Chrome URL but I get an error:

> System.MissingMethodException: 'Method not found: 'System.Windows.Rect System.Windows.Automation.Provider.IRawElementProviderFragment.get_BoundingRectangle()'.'

when I use this code

```
 Dim procsChrome As Process() = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome")
    For Each chrome As Process In procsChrome
        If chrome.MainWindowHandle = IntPtr.Zero Then Continue For
        Dim elm As AutomationElement = AutomationElement.FromHandle(chrome.MainWindowHandle)
        Dim elmUrlBar As AutomationElement = elm.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, New PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Address and search bar"))
        If elmUrlBar IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim patterns As AutomationPattern() = elmUrlBar.GetSupportedPatterns()
            If patterns.Length > 0 Then
                Dim val As ValuePattern = DirectCast(elmUrlBar.GetCurrentPattern(patterns(0)), ValuePattern)
                If Not elmUrlBar.GetCurrentPropertyValue(AutomationElement.HasKeyboardFocusProperty) Then Debug.Print(LCase(val.Current.Value).Trim)
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

The error appears in this line

```
   Dim elm As AutomationElement = AutomationElement.FromHandle(chrome.MainWindowHandle)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try readding 'UIAutomationClient.dll' and 'UIAutomationTypes.dll'.

Take a look at the following code.

```
    Dim procs As Process() = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome")

    For Each p As Process In procs
        If p.MainWindowHandle = IntPtr.Zero Then Continue For
        Dim element As AutomationElement = AutomationElement.FromHandle(p.MainWindowHandle)
        If element Is Nothing Then Continue For
        Dim conditions As Condition = New AndCondition(New PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ProcessIdProperty, p.Id), New PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.IsControlElementProperty, True), New PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.IsContentElementProperty, True), New PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Edit))
        Dim elementx As AutomationElement = element.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, conditions)
        Console.WriteLine(TryCast((CType(elementx.GetCurrentPattern(ValuePattern.Pattern), ValuePattern)).Current.Value, String))
    Next
```

Comment: I added 'UIAutomationClient.dll' and 'UIAutomationTypes.dll' and import system.windows.Automation
but, I get the same error in that line
 Dim element As AutomationElement = AutomationElement.FromHandle(p.MainWindowHandle)

Comment: Maybe take a look at ：https://github.com/TestStack/White/issues/664#issuecomment-574277864